# AngularJS testing controller using a service returning a promise

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am writing unit tests for my components.

I know this question has been answered before and after researching quite a bit, it feels like testing something that relies on services is a hassle or requires dirty work.

For me, the following feels dirty and I request your opinion if this is the way to go or not :)

Here goes my Controller

```
function Login($location, AuthService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.error = "";

    vm.login = login;

    //////////

    function login(credentials) {
        AuthService.login(credentials)
            .then(function(user) {
                $location.path("/menu");
            })
            .catch(function(q) {
                vm.error = q.data.error;
            });
    }
}
```

The test preparation, where I fake `$location` and my `AuthService`:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($q) {
    location = {
        path: function(q) { path = q; }
    };

    AuthService = {
        login: function(credentials) {
            deferred = $q.defer();
            if (credentials)
                deferred.resolve();
            else
                deferred.reject({ data: {error: "My Error"} });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
}));

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    Login = $controller('Login', {
        $location: location,
        AuthService: AuthService
    });
}));
```

and the tests:

```
describe("(login)", function() {
    it('should redirect on successful login', function() {
        Login.login(true);
        scope.$root.$digest();
        expect(path).toBe("/menu");
    });

    it('should show error on failed login', function() {
        Login.login(false);
        scope.$root.$digest();
        expect(Login.error).toBe("My Error");
    });
});
```

Everything is working, but it feels dirty using global variables and checking after the fact.

I appreciate every opinion and every cleaner way to go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be a cleaner approach

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, $controller, _AuthService_, _$location_, _$q_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    AuthService = _AuthService_;
    $location = _$location_;
    $q = _$q_;

    spyOn($location, 'path').and.stub();

    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    Login = $controller('Login', { $scope: scope });
}));

describe("(login)", function() {
    it('should redirect on successful login', function() {
        spyOn(AuthService, 'login').and.returnValue($q.resolve());

        Login.login(true);
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect($location.path).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/menu');
    });

    it('should show error on failed login', function() {
        spyOn(AuthService, 'login').and.returnValue($q.reject({
            data: {error: "My Error"}
        }));

        Login.login(false);
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect(Login.error).toBe("My Error");
    });
});
```

`path` global doesn't look good (even if it is local variable in `describe` scope), you don't have to do the spies' job for them.

Comment: That is indeed a cleaner way, thank you! One more thing tho, why do you generate a new `$scope` which you hand to the Login controller and in the test you work with `$rootScope`.

Comment: It may be the same in your case, but it is a good habit to do it, because directive or controller may presume the existence of parent scope.